# `org-re-reveal` custom slide keyboard bindings

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

Per the [`reveal.js` docs on keyboard bindings](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#keyboard-bindings), I'd like to find a way to configure the keyboard bindings in the following way:

```js
Reveal.configure({
  keyboard: {
    // left, down -> next
    40: 'next', // ↓
    39: 'next', // ->
    // right, up -> prev
    37: 'prev', // <-
    38: 'prev', // ↑
    // return, space -> down
    13: 'down', // <RET>
    32: 'down', // <SPC>
    // backspace -> up
    8:  'up' // <BSPC>
  }
});
```

with `org-re-reveal`, but I'm stuck on how to actually do that either on a per-file (which is preferred) or global basis. I tried saving the above javascript as `kbd-config.js` in the same directory as my `presentation.org` and putting

```
#+REVEAL_INIT_SCRIPT: kbd-config.js
```

on a line towards with the top of `presentation.org` (along with `#+OPTIONS: ...`), but that lead to a blank presentation.

(Context: this would be a useful customization because my presentation remote only has buttons that correspond to `ArrowUp` and `ArrowDown`. I'm not sure what a better work-around would be, especially because this at least gives me the option of going over to the computer and navigating `up` and `down` if I really want to.)

Edit:

I renamed `kbd-config.js` to `kbd.js` and updated it in the following manner:

```js
function () {
  return { keyboard: {
    // left, down -> next
    40: 'next', // ↓
    39: 'next', // ->
    // right, up -> prev
    37: 'prev', // <-
    38: 'prev', // ↑
    // return, space -> down
    13: 'down', // <RET>
    32: 'down', // <SPC>
    // backspace -> up
    8:  'up' // <BSPC>
  }}};
```

and included the line `#+REVEAL_INIT_SCRIPT:./kbd.js` in `presentation.org`, which produced the same blank slideshow. My browser's console had two errors:

```
presentation.html:115 GET file:///Users/matlock/technical/install/reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
presentation.html:147 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

The second error pointed to this block

```html
<script>
// Full list of configuration options available here:
// https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
Reveal.initialize({

controls: true,
progress: true,
history: false,
center: true,
slideNumber: 'c',
rollingLinks: false,
keyboard: true,
mouseWheel: false,
fragmentInURL: false,
pdfSeparateFragments: true,

overview: true,

theme: Reveal.getQueryHash().theme, // available themes are in /css/theme
transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'slide', // see README of reveal.js for options
transitionSpeed: 'default',

// Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
dependencies: [
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }]

,./kbd.js});
</script>
```

which is where the problem seems to occur. Clearly there's an issue with the way I'm trying to include JavaScript, but I simply don't know how to do it.

Comment: The error message you're getting in the browser might be helpful. Try opening developer tools and going to the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

Including `#+REVEAL_EXTRA_JS:  { src: './kbd-config.js' }` at the top actually seems to work. Looking in Chrome's `Developer Tools -> Applications -> Frames -> top -> presentation.html`, the `dependencies` list has been updated as follows:

```html
// Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
dependencies: [
{ src: './kbd-config.js' },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
 { src: 'file:///path/to/reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }]

});
```